# Android: I have some errors in a code sequence

Tags: android

I have a problem with this code sequence.

```
question= Common.questionList.get(questionIndex);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW7aR.jpg
If i comment this line , I get an error at line 292

```
txt_wrong_answer.setText(String.valueOf(0));
```

if I comment on it too , the program runs but can not finish the game.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH3yv.jpg

Comment: What error you get on 292?

Comment: Also the first error is because your index is -1 and there is no such position in array. Try setting default value 0 not -1.

Comment: i set value 0 : https://imgur.com/a/UTMurxf

Comment: There is no refence set `txt_wrong_answer` Its null. Clearly the message says so. Where do you set `txt_wrong_answer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first error, you are accessing -1 of the array. There is no such position hence `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception is thrown. I would put default value 0 not -1.
`questionIndex = getArguments().getInt("index", 0)`
I would also advice to check, or make sure, that `questions` array has at least one element. Because if it would be empty, 0 would throw the same error as well.

For the second error, your reference `txt_wrong_answer` is not yet set in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Make sure you set it before you call `.setText` on it or handle with an if block `if (txt_wrong_answer != null)`

Answer (score 0):

replace this question= Common.questionList.get(questionIndex); to below code

```
if(questionIndex >= 0 && questionIndex < Common.questionList.size()){
     question= Common.questionList.get(questionIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but he did not help me